# javascript create a video element on element not working in state blob url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I am cloning an element in developing a Chrome extension for video. However setting the `src` attribute to the url of a `video` element is not working.

I am using xhr in javascript to get file in the browser.

```js
var copyCustomePlayer = function (video, element) {  
    var videoHtml = "<video id=\"extensionVideo" + 1 + "\" 
        class=\"extension-video-player\" controls></video>";
    var videoElement = $.parseHTML(videoHtml)[0];
    videoElement.currentSrc = video.currentSrc;
    videoElement.src = video.src;
    videoElement.currentTime = video.currentTime;       
    element.appendChild(videoElement);
    body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more information - what error do you get in the console? What is the actual value of  `video.src` - you say you are using "xhr in javascript" to get the file - can you show where you set your xhr responseType?

Comment: status response xhr is 404(not found)

videoElement.currentSrc = ""blob:http://www.xxxx.com/a8723d6e-89ab-479f-98d7-107eb4aadcb5""

Comment: So the issue is that the file can't be found (404) - are you sure the blob uri is correct and accessible from the domain you are trying from? If that is not the case really you would need to post a complete example that shows the problem fully.

Comment: Blob url in videos site we.telegram.org is ok, but blob url in site aparat.com is not found!

Comment: I use in function clone() jquery for duplicat video element, but not found url for play video